# Como puedo hacer un PUT de postman a laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy creando una simple api en laravel y quiero ejecutar el metodo put y delete,
hasta ahora el metodo get y post me funcionan, pero a la hora de actualizar un registro no se que estoy haciendo mal

este es mi codigo de controlador

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
  $ave = Ave::findOrFail($request->id);
  print_r($ave);
  $ave->nombre = $request->nombre;
  $ave->save();
  return $ave;
}
```

las rutas de mi api

```
Route::get('/aves', 'App\Http\Controllers\AveController@index');
Route::post('/aves', 'App\Http\Controllers\AveController@store');
Route::put('/aves{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AveController@update');
Route::delete('/aves{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AveController@destroy');
```

la peticion en postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si vas a mandar la id dentro del json, tenés mal definidas las rutas `'/aves{id}'` tendría que ser `'/aves'` para que conicida con lo que estás poniendo en postman. O a la inversa, tendrías que adaptar la url que pones en postman, para que coincida con lo que tienes en laravel

Comment: me funciono quitando el id del controlador, pero como lo podría mandar con el {id} de esta forma?

Comment: Podrías definir tu ruta así `Route::put('/aves/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AveController@update');`, en el controlador recibes ese id como argumento `public function update(Request $request, $id) { $ave = Ave::findOrFail($id);` y en postman apuntas a `/api/aves/1` donde ese `1` será el valor de la variable `$id` que recibe el controlador